# Probability of Default calculation

Tags: credit-risk, default-probability

I am looking for some good resources with handful of workout examples, on the modelling of the `Probability of Default` under `IFRS9` framework.

Could you please point me towards some good resources on this subject on how Banks typically calculate them?

Any insight will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

IFRS 9 requires a bank to have a probability of defaut (PD) and a loss given defaut (LGD) and other models.

I looked at [Tiziano Bellini *IFRS 9 and CECL Credit Risk Modelling and Validation: A Practical Guide with Examples Worked in R and SAS*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012814940X) and it helped me understand what's being done.

I also plan to look at [Jing Zhang *The New Impairment Model Under IFRS 9 and CECL*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782723471) when I get to it.