# How do i calculate the Current Expected Credit Loss Model (CECL)

Tags: ifrs9

how do i calculate the CECL?
The equation for the Expected Loss Model (ECL) is:

$ EL=PD*EAD*LGD$ (Lifetime ECL for Stage 2 & 3)

I would like to do a comparative calculation for my bachelor thesis. I have already calculated all impairments for the incurred and expected loss model. (Table is in German: Risikovorsorge = Loan loss provision; Zeitpunkt = Time)

***Can someone show me how to calculate the CECL?***

**Nominal amount: 1.000.000€**

**Duration: 4 Years**

**Interest rate: 5%**

[image]
[image]

Comment: You may find the references here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59233/probability-of-default-calculation/59244#59244 helpful

Comment: hey, thank you for the literature tips!
They have definitely brought me further.
Unfortunately, I still haven't quite solved the problem and need help with the calculation in Excel.